# Designing Form Using Twitter Bootstrap for column type Input

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design a form something like this:

[image]

I went through the documentation of Twitter Bootstrap and found that there is no proper way of doing it unless you do some CSS hacks over to achieve that. I don't want to do any CSS hacks because they make the page unresponsive.

Is there any proper way for achieving this ?

I have come up with the following code for my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="input-mini" for="first">Start</label>
        <label class="input-mini" for="first">End</label>
        <label class="input-mini" for="first">Share</label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mzs2/9/). There are two problems with the above form being rendered:

1. Labels are not horizontal.
2. The space between text input is not proper.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can achieve that layout with the help of the grid.

Something like this should do the work:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span1">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        Three
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span1">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <input type="text" class="input-mini">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Same as above -->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Same as above -->
  </div>
</div>
```

See the demo here: http://bootply.com/60908

Comment: Thanks. I previously tried this solution. The problem with this one is that when it is switched to mobile layout, all the rows of the form are stacked vertically against each other even though they have extra space in front of them.

Comment: @Sibi What behaviour do you want with mobile layout? Do you want the form to keep the same layout?

Comment: In the mobile layout, I want to keep the same layout. The rows should not get stacked vertically.

Comment: @Sibi AFAIK there isn't any solution with pure bootstrap. If you want that, I think you have to use some CSS tricks.

Comment: CSS tricks should be fine if they make the form responsive in mobile layout.